# How do you access a second USB drive from Tails?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails

I am running Tails 1.3.1 off of a USB stick and want to save files onto a second USB stick from the Tor Browser.  I can see and access files that were on the second USB stick from the file browser but cannot access it through the save dialog in Tor Browser.  I get the error `Could not read the contents of (DRIVE NAME), Permission Denied`.

I can't seem to change the permissions from "Amnesia" group.  Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

Tails 1.3.1 took the special step of isolating the Tor Browser from the rest of the operating system. When Tor Browser saves things (e.g., downloads) it saves them to its own, isolated folder. The folder can be made persistent.

If you want to make something on your USB stick accessible to the Tor Browser, you must copy it to the Tor Browser directory, which is a subdirectory of the home directory. Likewise, if you download something and you want to use it from the desktop, then you must specifically copy it to the desktop. The easiest way to do that, of course, is to use the Places menu item to browse to the Tor Browser folder, and copy the item from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
vi /etc/apparmor.d/torbrowser
```

find existing file/directory-access -related lines in that file, eg:

```
...
owner "@${HOME}/Tor Browser/" rw,
owner "@${HOME}/Tor Browser/**" rwk,
...
```

add your own, for example:

```
owner "/media/" rw,
owner "/media/**" rwk,
```

then as a root:

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor reload
```

and also change owner of said path to amnesia:

```
chown -R amnesia:amnesia /media/
```

done